# Include a file multiple times with different names in a Gradle-built JAR

Tags: java, localization, gradle, resourcebundle

I work with Java resource bundles that are included in the final JAR using the standard resource processing provided by the java plugin. The file structure is the following:

```
src
└── main
    ├── java
    └── resources
        ├── com
        │   └── example
        │       └── lang
        │           ├── localization.properties
        │           └── localization_en.properties
        └── folder-with-unrelated-resources
```

Due to the nature of the automatic resource loading, I need to include the English file two times: As the standard English file (`localization_en.properties`) and as the base file that provides a fallback if a more specific localization is not found (`localization.properties`). At the moment, both of these files are present in the resource directory, even through their content is exactly the same.

I am looking for a way that let Gradle duplicate the present `localization_en.properties` and include it with the base name, so I do not need two separated files in the resource directory. I assume I need to hook into the `ProcessResources` task, but I have no idea on how to create the duplicate of the `localization_en.properties` file and add it to the processed resources.

Comment: Looks like you don't need the language/locale specific variant at all. If both files are identical just go with the default file (localization.properties). Add more specific variants if and only if you need them.

Comment: @fateddy No both are needed because Java's bundle lookup also takes the JVM's locale into account. E.g. `localization_de.properties` and `localization.properties` (in English) are present. The JVM's locale is `de_DE` and the bundle for `en_US` is requested. Java can't find it but it can find a bundle matching the JVM's default locale so it uses that before falling back to the base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you copy the resources with `gradle`:

```
task copyLocalizations(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/resources')
    into(sourceSets.main.output.resourcesDir)
    include('localization.properties')
    rename('localization.properties', 'localization_en.properties')
}

processResources.dependsOn(copyLocalizations)
```

But I think there is an even better way to overcome the JVM defaults -> set the default locale programmatically (eg. to the ROOT locale):

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ROOT);
```

Therefore your application would be independent to environment configs (and in general more robust).